# How can I get a list of users and last login dates from a Cisco ACS running v5.2?

Tags: cisco, aaa, logging

I'm trying to get a list of the users that have logged into a Cisco ACS, and the date of their last login.  Ideally, I'd like it to include the identity store that was the source of the authentication info for the login (AD, RADIUS, etc.)  I've looked in the ACS GUI, including monitoring and reports, but I mainly find things referencing monitoring the device's status itself, or broad trends.  The one section that lists user information does it for one user at a time (not practical for a large pool of users).
     I've looked online but so far all I can find is someone telling how to do it in version 4, nothing for 5.2.  Cisco's own documents don't seem to mention it either.  As a side note, upgrading the software version is not an option at this time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the Cisco TAC representative who handled my case, there is no way to get a list of users that includes their last login date, with the possible exception of looking up each user individually.  I'm not sure I believe this answer, as it seems like such a basic query that I'd be very surprised if they didn't include any way to get the answer, but that is the word from Cisco themselves.

I am going to persist in trying to find a way to get that list, and if I succeed, I will update this answer.

Answer (score -2):

Just look in the Administrator Guide for "accounting" which is one of the A's in AAA.

http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/net_mgmt/cisco_secure_access_control_server_for_windows/4-2/user/guide/ACS4_2UG/LgsRpts.html

[image]

Comment: That is for version 4.2   It does not work for version 5.2, which is the one I need assistance with, as specified in the question.  But thank you for your time.

Comment: See [Monitoring & Report Viewer System Operations](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/net_mgmt/cisco_secure_access_control_system/5-3/user/guide/acsuserguide/viewer_sys_ops.html)

Comment: Also [Available Reports in the Catalog](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/net_mgmt/cisco_secure_access_control_system/5-2/user/guide/acsuserguide/viewer_reporting.html#wp1121647)

Comment: Neither of those tell how to get a list of users with their last login dates, unless I missed it, but I've looked them over several times.  The Available Reports table doesn't specifically mention being able to do this, so I'm wondering if it's even possible.  But it seems like a very basic query to run; if Cisco left no way to do it I'll be pretty surprised.  Thanks again for your suggestions.

Comment: [Authentication Records and Details](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/net_mgmt/cisco_secure_access_control_system/5-2/user/guide/acsuserguide/monit_report.html#wp1077508)

Comment: You may need to specifically syslog RADIUS and then view it with a viewer like WhatsUpGold?  However, id be very surprised if this basic data isn't viewable via ACS.  Open a Cisco TAC Case if you have to,

Comment: Kiwi Syslog Server... That's the free one I was thinking about.  Just remembered it.

Comment: Thanks Ron, your suggestions are appreciated.  I may have to open a case with Cisco like you suggested.

Comment: np, glad to help

Comment: [Look here](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/net_mgmt/cisco_secure_access_control_system/5-2/device_support/sdt52.html#wp71811) and [here](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/security/secure-access-control-system/113639-ptn-113639.html).  It appears you can have a remote Microsoft or Oracle SQL server as the View DB.  If it's all in SQL just create or find a read only account and run SQL queries to get what you want.  SQL Queries are not hard to learn/use.